URP Build looks different than Editor?
I can't seem to figure out why my URP scenes in the Editor look different than the scenes in my Build.
I am on Unity 2022.3.15f1 (tested on both MacOS and Windows 10) and have had the same result on 2022.3.24f1 when I tried upgrading.
I have tried the following recommended by the attached links:

Baking lighting settings into scene

Removing SSAO from my URP asset

Ensuring my quality settings are correct

Upgrading Unity version

Reflection probe workaround

Changing the shader precision model


I have not tired:

downgrading, but this is something I would like to avoid resorting to

changing post processing settings

the solution lol


Here is the scene from the Editor:

and here is the scene from the Build:

and lastly here are some of my settings:

and my URP asset settings:


I am an idiot, I found the error and it was incredibly simple.
I accidentally tagged my rendering root GameObject (with all of my various rendering settings) as EditorOnly within all of my scenes.
I'll leave this post up (as oppose to deleting it) as it is a decent enumerator for the most common fixes for this problem.
